# Question on a job application form

Tags: ambiguity

I'm helping a friend fill out a job application where a strange question appears:

> Do you seldom let your responsibilities interfere with having fun?  (Y) (N)

Am I crazy, or is this question ambiguously worded?  Which response would an employer look more favorably upon?

Comment: Follow-up question: "Do you infrequently beat your wife?"

Comment: @joe, you'd tick "yes"? As in "Yes, it is RARE that I let my responsibilities to my employer, family, and friends TAKE PRIORITY over parrrrrrrtttyyy tiiiimmmme!"?

Comment: Getting back to the question and whether it is ambiguous: to me, it seems clear the employer wants you to answer "no", meaning "no, I won't blow off work to hit the beach if it happens to be a particularly sunny Wednesday". Can anyone see a way to interpret the question such that "yes" would be the desirable answer from the employer's POV? That a yes-answerer would make a more desirable employee than a no-answerer?

Comment: So, to answer @Paul's question explicitly: ***yes***, the question ***is*** ambiguous. (But I have to say that I find it a little implausible that an employer would ask a question that *bakes in the assumption that you're going to slack off*, and they just want your assurance that it won't be that often. That's way too forthright for most job applications. Thus, I think the safer bet is to interpret the question such that answering "no" confirms you're *not going to slack off, even a little*.)

Comment: You're quite right: the fact is this: **the author could have meant either of the two likely meanings** {it's just conceivable they could have meant the third, actually obscure, literal meaning.}  We, literally, do not know which of the two the writer meant.  So yeah - it's that simple. It is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ambiguous, in the sense that, **seldom** is often used to mean "very rarely or never" but it can also mean "sometimes" (i.e. "not strictly never").

(It's true that "seldom" literally means, well, "seldom" (say "5% of the time") but the fact is it is often used in the two ways just described.)

Comment: +1. Actually, what I was saying is: the question *literally* reads "*Do you infrequently put **work** before **fun***", or, following your template, "*Do you **occasionally** put work before fun?*". (PS: per your "concise answer first, elaboration later" advice to me yesterday, I suggest you start this answer off with "***Yes**, the question **is ambiguous.***")

Comment: I've just realised some sentences are literally ambiguous ("Where did the dog bite you?")  But some sentences are literally not ambiguous ("do you do it seldom") but there are common (say "messy") usages which render the sentence ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not necessarily ambiguously worded, but it may be intended to see just how closely the applicant reads. Seldom letting one's responsibilities interfere with having fun would that most of the time when a friend calls to say he want's to go somewhere on a workday, you decline the friends offer and go to work. If you answer "no" to the question the way it is worded, it might mean that when your friend calls, you frequently go with your friend instead of going to work.

I would expect that most employers would want to see the question answered "yes".

Comment: would *mean* that

Comment: right, it's not ambiguous at all.  it's simply "wrong": i.e. the writer was not capable of expressing what the writer actually meant.

Comment: So, if you are a very responsible person, who will always prioritise (work) responsibilities over fun, hence, you truthfully answer _no_ to this question, the employer will not like it. Because, hey, responsible people are not what employers are looking for. This question is plain idiotic unless you are really only looking for either middle-of-the-road candidates or extremes - on both sides!

Comment: Joe, you may be right. But I'm remembering a person I once knew who had hiring authority, and always took a candidate to lunch before making a job offer. A candidate who added salt and pepper to his or her food before tasting it, never got an answer, because the hiring authority took that as a sign that the prospective candidate was too likely to make decisions without all the facts. (continued)

Comment: (Continued from above) I'm also remembering a test I took in about 4th grade, consisting of two pages of instructions. The first was to read the entire test before making a mark on the paper, the second was to write one's name in the upper left hand corner. All but one of the others were for things like making three circles at the bottom of the page, punching a hole in the paper at a particular point, &c. But the 20th question was to go back and only do the second instruction. The aim of the test was to test the ability to follow directions.